# jQuery using sprites - putting more than one effect, can be a syntax problem

Tags: jquery, css, sprite

I'm studying jQuery, but I still encounter issues I can't find a solution for. This time, I'm using sprites to animate a page. I can make one work, but I have two problems:
1) The effect doesn't stop on mouseout as it should (I would like the animation to reset and go back to grey); and
2) I can't make it work for more than one button. It's like the first code is still running and won't allow the second (I need 4) to start.

JS Fiddle with two buttons (edited - route fixed): http://jsfiddle.net/U9zvL/10/

So my script has an error / is missing something, and I'm not sure if that's the cause why the second script doesn't work.

Scripts:

```
<script  type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#Q1animation").mouseenter(function() {
            $('#Q1animation').sprite({fps: 18, no_of_frames: 5, play_frames: 5});
            });
        $('#Q1animation').destroy();
        $("#Q1animation").mouseleave(function() {
            $('#Q1animation').spStop(true);
        });
});  
</script>

<script  type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#Q2animation").mouseenter(function() {
            $('#Q2animation').sprite({fps: 18, no_of_frames: 5, play_frames: 5});
            });
        $('#Q2animation').destroy();
        $("#Q2animation").mouseleave(function() {
            $('#Q2animation').spStop(true);
        });
});  
</script>
```

Thank you for ANY help you can give me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Chrome console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert null to object    jquery.spritely-0.5.js:478
```

which is this line of code:

```
destroy: function() {
    var el = $(this);
    var el_id = $(this).attr('id');
    delete $._spritely.instances[el_id] // <--- HERE
    return this;
}
```

so it looks like the problem is that you're trying to spritely-`destroy` before you have called spritely initialization on the object, which the library does not handle well. Try removing the `.destroy()` calls (other code cleanup performed as well):

```
$(function() {
    $("#Q1animation, #Q2animation").mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).sprite({
            fps: 18,
            no_of_frames: 5,
            play_frames: 5
        });
    }).mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).spStop(true);
    });
});
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/9KWp5/

---

#### Edit - got it working

```
$(function() {
    $("#Q1animation, #Q2animation").mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).sprite({
            fps: 18,
            no_of_frames: 5,
            play_frames: 5
        });
    }).mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).spStop(true).destroy();
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/7z9xe/

Comment: As @Eonasdan answered, you also need to change one of the URLs in the CSS.

Comment: Hi Matt. First of all, thank you!. Secondly, although animations work now, when mouseout they stop working forever&ever. Script looks great now, though, but I don't really understand what the problem with .destroy was and if it has to do with this last malfunctioning...

Comment: Do you think there is any other way of doing this, perhaps using other libraries?

Comment: Re: your second question - of course there's another way to do it. There always is.

Comment: But this means this one can't be fixed? Any ideas on what else to use? My client wants the color to appear like this, I can't imagine how to do it without sprites. And I'm desperate!

Comment: I'm still playing around with it. Unfortunately the spritely documentation is lacking...

Answer (score 0):

you're going to face palm yourself for this but, the css in your jsfiddle script show be:

```
http://metrosafety-dev.co.uk/images/custom/Q2sprite.png
```

and not

```
http://metrosafety-dev.co.uk/images/custom/custom/Q2sprite.png
```

**Edit:** I did get the same error as @Matt Ball with the .destroy() comment these lines out allows both to work. However the animations only run once

Comment: I would LOVE to facepalm myself in exchange for the solution xD but the /custom/ was unfortunately only a fiddle mistake (I'm working with local files) :s